# SQL Server WHERE Clause with optional parameter not working as expected

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a query shown below. The parameter `@company` is optional from .NET code.

When I pass the value, it is working as expected and bringing matching results for this `@company`. When I don't pass a value, it should return more rows, for all all other companies also. Somehow it is not returning anything.

I know we can write dynamic SQL and add that condition if it is not null. But is there any other better short cut to do this?

Appreciate your responses.

```
declare @company varchar(20) = 'AAA'

select distinct 
    fname as first_name, u.lname as last_name, 
    sc.company as employed_by, 
    sc.short_description as employed_by_company_name, 
    u.user_code
from 
    users u
inner join 
    sis_companies sc on sc.company = u.company 
inner join 
    sis_carriers car on sc.company = sc.company
inner join 
    carrier_shipper_contact_roles cashro on car.carrier = cashro.carrier
where 
    cashro.carrier = 'CPL'
    and (isnull(sc.company, '') = '' or sc.company = @company)
```

Thanks

Comment: `or @company IS NULL`?

Comment: When i pass null, this condition is working. Since I defaulted the optional parameters to Emptystring , in that scenario it is not bringing back anything.

Comment: please show the code where you "default to emptystring" -- is this in the C#?

Comment: "Since I defaulted the optional parameters to Emptystring", you should have mentioned that. Then `or @company = ''`?, I mean, seems logical

Comment: @Hogan I don't think so. Op's problem is about using the `@company` parameter

Comment: @Lamak; Adding that condition too worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Lamak said you should **not** use ISNULL(SC.Company,'')='' to get all companies

you should have as follows

```
select 
    distinct fname as first_name, u.lname as last_name, 
    sc.company as employed_by
        , sc.short_description as employed_by_company_name, u.user_code
    from users u
        inner join sis_companies sc on sc.company = u.company 
            inner join sis_carriers car on sc.company = sc.company
            inner join carrier_shipper_contact_roles cashro on car.carrier = cashro.carrier
    Where cashro.carrier = 'CPL'
      and (@company is NULL or sc.company = @company)
```

Incase you want to pass empty string and get all companies too then

```
select 
    distinct fname as first_name, u.lname as last_name, 
    sc.company as employed_by
        , sc.short_description as employed_by_company_name, u.user_code
    from users u
        inner join sis_companies sc on sc.company = u.company 
            inner join sis_carriers car on sc.company = sc.company
            inner join carrier_shipper_contact_roles cashro on car.carrier = cashro.carrier
    Where cashro.carrier = 'CPL'
      and (NULLIF(@company,'') is NULL or sc.company = @company)
```

Comment: what about the case when the parameter is the empty string?

Comment: That part isn't actually in the question yet, so this answer is valid to the question asked

Comment: @Hogan Incase of Parameter is empty string do you want to get all companies too?

Comment: @pjobs - yes I believe that was the OP's goal.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this

```
and (isnull(@company, '') = '' or sc.company = @company)
```